# Camera shows "No Device Found"

Tags: camera

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on HP Elitebook 840 G4. For a few months, the camera is showing "No device found" when I open Cheese. Previously it was working fine. I can not even access the camera with any web application. I'm not sure if it is a hardware or software related problem. What could be the issue?

```
~$ sudo lshw --class video
Hardware Lister (lshw) - 
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

    -version        print program version ()

format can be
    -html           output hardware tree as HTML
    -xml            output hardware tree as XML
    -json           output hardware tree as a JSON object
    -short          output hardware paths
    -businfo        output bus information

options can be
    -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
    -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet          don't display status
    -sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
    -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
    -notime         exclude volatile attributes (timestamps) from output

:~$ /bin/ls -l /dev/video*;id
/bin/ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
uid=1000(username) gid=1000(username) groups=1000(username),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),138(libvirt)
```

Comment: Does `sudo lshw --class video` show anything? What does `/bin/ls /dev/video*;id` show? Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question.

Comment: Sorry, typo `/bin/ls -l /dev/video*;id`. I omitted the `-l` (long listing) flag.

Comment: I have edited the post with the command outputs