# Ubuntu 22.04: cannot find camera

Tags: webcam, mate, camera

my Ubuntu HP laptop cannot find its camera, so I cannot use video.

[Camera shows "No Device Found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392812/camera-shows-no-device-found) does not help.

From that question,

`sudo lshw -class video`

has the output

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:142 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX250]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:141 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
```

I can also do

`lsusb -v | grep Camera`

as suggested by [Integrated camera](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002722/integrated-camera)

gives errors:

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

the output from `lsusb` is huge, I don't want to put that much info here for brevity.

When I start up `cheese`, I get the following warnings on the terminal:

```
** Message: 16:26:26.963: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:19569): cheese-CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:19569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:19569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:19569): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:19569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:19569): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:19569): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:19569): CRITICAL **: 16:26:26.972: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

the about screen shows the following system info:

[image: about]

also, `lspci` lists

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake-U v1 4c Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SCS3
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
```

How can I get my camera/webcam working again?

Comment: Not enough info to answer. What model of laptop? What version of Ubuntu? It often helps to update your system firmware, but since you didn't give the model, we can't tell you what version is current.

Comment: @LiamProven I have a HP Envy laptop 17-ce1xxx on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  I've added a lot of info to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged in to windows on the same laptop, and I found that the camera also doesn't work there. On internet search, I find that one of the first checks is whether or not there is a switch to turn the camera off.

Such a switch is present on this laptop.  I moved the switch, and the Ubuntu partition again has a working camera.

Silly me.

Comment: For me the problem was the shutter was closed. 
Please see this: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-in/inspiron-14-5410-2-in-1-laptop/inspiron-5410-2-in-1-setup-and-specifications/using-the-privacy-shutter?guid=guid-514df42a-261e-493a-9ddb-08f3d2e3b8ab&lang=en-us